# What time frame are salaries typically offered in reference to?

Tags: salary, united-states

When a company in the United States makes a job offer, what is the time frame that is *typically* used to convey the salary to the candidate?

For example, $3,500 per month vs. $42,000 per year?

Comment: Why not just ask HR? They're not going to rescind the offer for asking a question and to be honest it's literally the only way you can get a certain answer.

Comment: So, I'm new here.  Is this question off-topic or do people simply think it's a poor question?

Comment: It's off topic because the we can't answer for HR.  We can only guess.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was hoping to learn more about common standards rather than an exact answer for my situation.  I'm sure the offer letter will have more details.

Comment: @Lilienthal that sounds like a great answer to my question.  Essentially, "there isn't a 'normal policy'."  Right?

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager no, it was a verbal offer.  I will just wait to see.  No matter what, this is going to be a significant improvement for me in many ways.  I would delete this question due to its unpopularity, but it already has an answer.

Comment: @KateGregory highly unlikely.  My current position is not salaried.

Comment: Going forward it is always good to remember that asking for clarification in a job offer is NEVER petty.   This is your career and life at stake and your responsibility to safeguard it.  Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Any salary I've heard referenced to is annual, but it makes no sense to have that if you're in the US since that's well under minimum wage.

You absolutely need to know what timescale they are talking about, and they are the only ones who will be able to tell you. It's not petty to ask about something that important. A quick call to HR is all you'll need, they'll let you know, and you can make an informed decision.

Comment: It is very much a regional/industry thing. Some places on this earth will refer to monthly salaries, some to weekly and others to annual.

Answer (score 2):

***Typically***, the time period is specified, to avoid any risk of confusion. Failing that, annual salary is the most common default assumption in the US; it may be different elsewhere, and there may be exceptions.

***Ask.*** Requesting clarification when needed is part of everyone's job description. (And as the Flying Karamazov Brothers point out, so is juggling.)